# Sort-Object not working

Tags: sorting, powershell, exchange-server

Why is this code not sorting the mailboxes by totalitemsize?

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -descending | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: I swear this same code has worked in the past.  What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like it is sorting, but it's sorting by the string representation of TotalItemSize rather than the numeric value.

Comment: @MrKWatkins you are right.  I just noticed that.  9-0, but not GB-KB.

Answer (score 0):

do it lke this:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
Sort-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.VALUE.TOMB() } -descending | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize
```

without the custom order, you sort using a string order and not by the size.

Comment: see my latest attached picture. @C.B.

Comment: @benknighthorse I've tested it on a exchange 2010 ad works, maybe you are in different version?

Comment: I have no clue what has happened, but this command used to work for me.  Something was have changed on my exchange server.  I am still investigating. @c.b.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution was posted to the PowerShell Magazine #PSTip column just yesterday.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/10/08/pstip-parsing-exchange-size-strings/

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics |
select-object Displayname, @{Name=MBSize;Expression={[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::Parse($_.TotalItemSize).ToMB();}}|
Sort-Object MBSize -descending | ft DisplayName, MBSize
```

I can't test this myself as I don't have an Exchange environment to point at.